# Properness on an open subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I was wondering if the following property holds in general

> > For any morphism $f: X \to Y$ between two varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, there exists a nonempty open subvariety $U \subseteq Y$ such that $f: f^{-1}(U) \to U$ is proper.

I know this is true when $f$ is a quai-finite morphism (i.e. the fibres only consisting finite points), but the proof I can think of is very indirect. I try to think of the problem in the analytic case where properness has a more geometry meaning, but I could not think of a counterexample.

Any suggestion in this kind of statement?

Comment: This statement is very far from being true. Consider the case where $Y$ is a point, for example.

Comment: ...or when $X=Y\times \mathbb A^n_\mathbb C$ .